# Query XML [SAML 2.0 Response]

Tags: c#, xml, saml-2.0

The below xml is causing me difficulty. I need to retrieve the following from the XML with c#, can you please help? Also is there a better way of reading/parsing SAML 2.0 response in c#?

- status code from `<samlp:StatusCode value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:**Success**"/>`
- FIRSTNAME Value
- LASTNAME Value
- MAIL Value
- Issuer from   `<saml:Issuer>**sso.localhost.dev**</saml:Issuer>`
- Audience from  `<saml:Audience>**Application-Test**</saml:Audience>`

XML

```
    <samlp:Response Destination="http://localhost/SamlAuthenticate" IssueInstant="2014-03-27T14:49:35.395Z" ID="kBWlU3VWF.Ee6DKbkEpFomtlDAT" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">sso.localhost.dev</saml:Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#kBWlU3VWF.Ee6DKbkEpFomtlDAT"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>LgH7ZZJWwp5fN02IPteWxh9oAQ8=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>gBCZ4upHHdYzrVUcTe4Nf+fElY51UFQOJcf81DFPFNKfFxZfLjnX88NwJ6O7CVU3YNo08EINoEpkvEu+f2oxI3VQVnYnT1EYpLGy1+6qpxsFaPbXaQ8h1/NCwAygir1NDu/sktAzRZ2tg2i5rVn2sevY3Y+47SKnB+hG4ukVHusmNumD0NXyKwKNPflG9XEhrLj3bw5xuftr5CAREX5s1VotANFs1HeJA7OE1Yq2yLhw7GmPsa1+fgYQh5tfFRCmvdnpVoiT+SXwoxlRSbWlf2BWgBOLbC8W4dhTpMFmp70lndk0Pwpnxj6z4jFAHT3z/SdGgm0Ow+TbuutceBIIAQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
</ds:Signature>
<samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status>
<saml:Assertion Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-03-27T14:49:35.404Z" ID="w4BForMipBizsG1TA7d9QzhCM0-" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<saml:Issuer>sso.localhost.dev</saml:Issuer>
<saml:Subject>
<saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">JSMITH009</saml:NameID>
<saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
<saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2014-03-27T14:54:35.404Z" Recipient="http://localhost/SamlAuthenticate"/></saml:SubjectConfirmation>
</saml:Subject>
<saml:Conditions NotOnOrAfter="2014-03-27T14:54:35.404Z" NotBefore="2014-03-27T14:44:35.404Z">
<saml:AudienceRestriction>
<saml:Audience>Application-Test</saml:Audience>
</saml:AudienceRestriction>
</saml:Conditions>
<saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-03-27T14:49:35.404Z" SessionIndex="w4BForMipBizsG1TA7d9QzhCM0-">
<saml:AuthnContext>
<saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
</saml:AuthnContext>
</saml:AuthnStatement>
<saml:AttributeStatement xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="FIRSTNAME">
<saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">john</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="MAIL">
<saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">john.smith@email.localhost.dev</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="LASTNAME"><saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">smith</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>
</saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got the solution!

```
public class SAMLProcessor
{

    #region Properties
    public string DecodedSAML { get; set; }
    public string EncodedeSAML { get; set; }
    public string Audience { get; set; }
    public string SubjectNameID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool AuthenticationStatus { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string ResponseID { get; set; }
    public bool VerifiedResponse { get; set; }
    public string SignatureValue { get; set; }
    public string SignatureReferenceDigestValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime AutheticationTime { get; set; }
    public string AuthenticationSession { get; set; }
    #endregion


    #region Ctror
    public SAMLProcessor(string rawSamlData)
    {
        EncodedeSAML = rawSamlData;
        // the sample data sent us may be already encoded, 
        // which results in double encoding
        if (rawSamlData.Contains('%'))
        {
            rawSamlData = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(rawSamlData);
        }

        // read the base64 encoded bytes
        string samlAssertion = Decode64Bit(rawSamlData);
        DecodedSAML = samlAssertion;
        SamlParser(DecodedSAML);
    }
    #endregion

    private static string Decode64Bit(string rawSamlData)
    {
        byte[] samlData = Convert.FromBase64String(rawSamlData);

        // read back into a UTF string
        string samlAssertion = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(samlData);
        return samlAssertion;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="samldata"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string SamlParser(string samlXMLdata)
    {

        //samldata = Decode64Bit("PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4=") + samldata;
        string samldata = samlXMLdata;

        if (!samldata.StartsWith(@"<?xml version="))
        {
            samldata = Decode64Bit("PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4=") + samldata;
        }

        string firstName = string.Empty;
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        samldata = samldata.Replace(@"\", "");
        xDoc.LoadXml(samldata);
        //xDoc.Load(new System.IO.TextReader());//Suppose the xml you have provided is stored in this xml file.

        XmlNamespaceManager xMan = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
        xMan.AddNamespace("samlp", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
        xMan.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
        xMan.AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");


        XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/samlp:Status/samlp:StatusCode/@Value", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.AuthenticationStatus = false;
            string statusCode = xNode.Value;
            if (statusCode.EndsWith("status:Success"))
            {
                this.AuthenticationStatus = true;
            }

        }

        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/@Destination", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.Destination = xNode.Value;
        }
        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/@IssueInstant", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.AutheticationTime = Convert.ToDateTime(xNode.Value);
        }
        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/@ID", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.ResponseID = xNode.Value;
        }
        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/saml:Issuer", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.Issuer = xNode.InnerText;
        }

        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/ds:Signature/ds:SignedInfo/ds:Reference/ds:DigestValue", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.SignatureReferenceDigestValue = xNode.InnerText;
        }
        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/ds:Signature/ds:SignatureValue", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.SignatureValue = xNode.InnerText;
        }
        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/@ID", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.AuthenticationSession = xNode.Value;
        }

        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/saml:Subject/saml:NameID", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.SubjectNameID = xNode.InnerText;
        }
        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/saml:Conditions/saml:AudienceRestriction/saml:Audience", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.Audience = xNode.InnerText;
        }

        //reverse order
        //</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute></saml:AttributeStatement></saml:Assertion></samlp:Response>

        //string xQryStr = "//NewPatient[Name='" + name + "']";

        //XmlNode matchedNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xQryStr);
        // samlp:Response  saml:Assertion saml:AttributeStatement saml:Attribute
        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/saml:AttributeStatement/saml:Attribute[@Name = 'FIRSTNAME']/saml:AttributeValue", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.FirstName = xNode.InnerText;
        }

        // samlp:Response  saml:Assertion saml:AttributeStatement saml:Attribute
        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/saml:AttributeStatement/saml:Attribute[@Name = 'MAIL']/saml:AttributeValue", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.Mail = xNode.InnerText;
        }

        // samlp:Response  saml:Assertion saml:AttributeStatement saml:Attribute
        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/saml:AttributeStatement/saml:Attribute[@Name = 'LASTNAME']/saml:AttributeValue", xMan);
        if (xNode != null)
        {
            this.LastName = xNode.InnerText;
        }

        return this.FirstName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to parse the XML, you can load it into an [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can also use the [Saml2Response](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/Kentor.AuthServices/Saml2Response.cs) class of the [Kentor.AuthServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices/) package to parse and validate the response.